# CAPTCHA for outsider visitors

Tags: selenium, ip-address, recaptcha

Is it possible that a website is showing CAPTCHA verification for visitors outside of US?

My client asked me to scrape a website which is showing me a CAPTCHA and not for him. If the website is blocking my IP address, how can I navigate unknown without them locating my IP address?

I hope my question is clear, I am a newbie .. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A website can show CAPTCHA based on IP location and any others parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it's a script running on the web page for all visitors. I switched to Tor browser and it's working just fine.